# Evaluate variable to integer with sed

Tags: bash, sed, echo, sh

This can be so easy to a people who know. I am almost finishing this command

```
echo VERSION=1.0 | sed 's/^VERSION=\([0-9]\).\([0-9]\)/VERSION=\1.\2+1/'
```

I only want to write `VERSION=1.1` . How can I evaluate `\2` to integer and sum +1..

Comment: why `sed`? awk/perl/python/ruby/.. ?

Comment: I am learning how to use sed (reading a book).. And i am starting to understand it :)

Comment: I see.. so at the moment you only got a hammer? :) http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/dc.sed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`bc`](http://ss64.com/bash/bc.html) command:

```
echo VERSION=`echo "1.0 + 0.1" | bc`
```

Results in:

```
VERSION=1.1
```

[`man bc`](http://ss64.com/bash/bc.html)

```
echo "VERSION="`echo "v=1.0; v+=0.1; v" | bc` > myFile.txt
cat myFile.txt

VERSION=1.1
```

Comment: This is stupid question, but I use this command to write a file, so how can I integrate that line with this. Because my variable are in `\2` so, how can I do this? This is not a normal programing language :)

Comment: You could set the version number to any variable, then echo that variable + 0.1 and pipe it to bc and redirect the output to the file.  Ill update my answer to show an example

Comment: Where is the initial value of VERSION coming from?

Comment: From my text file that will save the VERSION number. This will always increase and save in file again.

Answer (score 2):

of couse sed can do that. that's what **e** for. you can pass matched/replaced string to shell command using "e"

see the example based on your sed line:

```
kent$  echo VERSION=1.0 | sed 's/^VERSION=\([0-9]\).\([0-9]\)/echo "VERSION=\1.$((\2+1))"/e'                                             
VERSION=1.1
```

Comment: Nice, didnt know `sed` could do that!

Comment: well it is not a common option. awk is better in this case. For fun one can in a sed script /e to another sed script then another sed... I did it once after 4+ nesting, I don't know where I am....

Comment: I am using the Mac OS X Lion terminal and sh 3.2 and it don't work, its my fault or it only run in linux?, It give `sed: 1: "s/^VERSION=\([0-9]\).\( ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'e' `

Comment: @Rodrigo I don't have a mac, so I cannot do the test. The command worked on bash/zsh with GNU sed 4.2.1. on my linux box. And I think sed version number shouldn't be the problem, I've used 'e' in lower version. Is your sed gnu?

Comment: I get the same error on my mac, but the exact same command works on my linux box... looking into the differences now.

Comment: The e flag at the end is a GNU extension.

Comment: [This is a GNU sed extension.](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)

Answer (score 1):

Crpytic answer - how to use the whole toolkit:

```
x='VERSION=1.0'
echo -n $x | sed 's/\..*/./'; expr `echo $x | grep -o '\..*' | cut -c 2-` + 1
```